# Put TextBlock on top of another TextBlock

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, visibility, textblock, dockpanel

I tried to implement case in which one `TextBlock` appears on top of another `TextBlock`, playing with `Visibility` property - but it doesn't working yet.

`TextBlock` are inside `DockPanel`:

```
<DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="5">
    <TextBlock Text="Text1" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right" DockPanel.Dock="Right">
        <TextBlock Text="Text2" Background="Aqua" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="{Binding IfDeviceSelected, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Converter={StaticResource  ResourceKey=BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
    </TextBlock>

    <TextBlock Text="@Device Focus:" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Can we see the code? And images of what happens?

Comment: DockPanel won't stack one textblock on top of another. Maybe you need a Grid instead?

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use a `Grid` to group these `TextBlocks`, `DockPanel/StackPanel` will not allow overlapping controls(without horrible manipulation of Margins etc)

```
  <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" >
     <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Right" >
         <TextBlock Text="Text1" />
         <TextBlock Text="Text2" Background="Aqua" Visibility="{Binding IfDeviceSelected, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Converter={StaticResource  ResourceKey=BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
     </Grid>
     <TextBlock Text="@Device Focus:" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
  </DockPanel>
```